# IE removes hashtag in URLs

Tags: internet-explorer, url, hashtag

I have defined urls in javascript variable, and every url is in format http://www.something.com/state-name#alabama

But in IE 7,8,9 it opens only site without that hashtag, it simply ignores it.

Do you know why is that and is there a way to fix it?

Thanks.

Comment: What is the expected behavior?

Comment: It must go to the site with hashtag, it is on the same page where is that link. But it only goes to the site without hashtag.

Comment: You mean, it does not scroll to the correct location on page?

Comment: How is the location identified on the page?

Comment: Yes, it does not scroll. It just go to the site. It is defined this way: <tr>
   <td colSpan="2" class="SubHeader"><a name="connecticut" title="connecticut"></a>Connecticut</td>
  </tr>